# OpenCV: 6 camera of car Bird's Eye View

Tags: opencv

I have [6 cameras in a car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HfCf.png) that cover 360 degrees of the surroundings. I know the translation and rotation of them and the intrinsic matrix of the camera. I am wondering how to get a bird's eye view of the car ([like this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uh5aUJ4TMyc/maxresdefault.jpg)) using the function `getPerspectiveTransform` . Specifically, I know I need 4 pairs of points to do transformation but I don't know how to determine them using translation and rotation of cameras.

Comment: with camera intrinsics and extrinsics you can generate 4 rays from each camera center through pixels and compute the point where they intersect the ground plane. Then you have 4 point pairs for each camera. Another way is to capture images with 4 markers on the ground and measured positions of those markers (for each camera).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you elaborate on the details of implementation since I am a total newbie? @Micka.

Comment: sorry, the first solution is far beyond the scope of this platform. The second solution is very simple. Just place markers on the ground (4 visible in each image), define an origin of your vehicle (center, or back, or front maybe) and measure the x/y/z real world distances from the origin to the markers. Search the pixel coordinates of all the markers in the camera images and then you have your real-world-to-camera-image point correspondences for your perspective transforms.

Comment: for the first solution you will have to understand virtual camera models (like openGL) and need some understanding of 3D geometry. To project points from the camera to the world, you can use the formula for depth sensors from http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration (projected to metric 3D space) but you will further have to apply the extrinsic parameters and the lens undistortion.

Comment: Ok, I will try both methods. You save my day! @Micka